# form_for, url parameter based on parent's id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have my routes setup fine and they are working as follows:

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :meal do
    resources :entre, :side, :desert
  end
end
```

In the meal index view, I generate, through a bunch of partials an :entre form as follows

```
<%= div_for meal do %>
  <tr>
    <td> <%= link_to "Meal #{meal.id}", meal %> </td>
    <td> <div class ="comment"><%= meal.comment %></div></td>
  <td></td>
    <td><div class ="Edit">
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_meal_path(meal) %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', meal, method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm:     'Are y
    </div></td>
    <td><div class ="vmaction">


      <%= form_for(meal.entres.new(params[:id])) do |f| %>
        <%= f.textfield :choice %>
        <%= f.submit "submit" %>
      <% end %>


    </div></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

As you can see above I am calling a view for another object in the line

```
<%= form_for(meal.entres.new(params[:id])) do |f| %>
```

I am trying to figure out how to add in the url parameter, so that based on the url, the `_Entres_ controller` will know which `meal_id` the entre is being submited for...

I basically want that form to generate a submit url along the lines of this when submitting an entre for say `meal_id=3`

```
http://website/meal/3/entres/new
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a meal along with a new entre in the form_for.  These will get rails to build the url with the meal_id in the route.

Something like this:

```
<%= form_for([meal, meal.entres.new]) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me clear something.
is it something like, `Meal` `has_many` `Entre` association?

Did you tried this:

in your `new` of `entres_controller` put :

```
@meal = Meal.find(3) #what ever you want to find out.
@entre = @meal.entres.build
```

and in your view:

```
<%= form_for [@meal, @entre] do |f| %>
```